# CSS: How to select a ul - within a div - within another div - within a header - within an article class

Tags: css

First-time poster, owner of a small business. I'm a novice who edits code to tweak the site. I'm not a developer. Please be gentle.

My site displays dates for news posts (good) and for my FAQs (not wanted).
The div class is the same for both, so when I hide the FAQ date, the news post date gets hidden as well.
I'm trying to figure out how to select more specifically. The "article" level contains the most specific tag that pertains specifically to the FAQ.

Can I select by article class and work my way down? I believe that should be possible, but if it is, I can't figure out the syntax. Below is NOT the syntax I've attempted; it's just to illustrate the hierarchy:

```
article class="faq"
header class="generic-header-name-thats-found-elsewhere-in-site"
div class="generic-div-name-also-found-elsewhere"
div class="generic-child-div-name"
ul class="generic-ul-class-name"
```

All I want to do is hide that unordered list class if it happens to occur with the "faq" article class. It would be cleaner if my news posts and faq posts used unique tags, but they don't, and dealing with that is well beyond me.

Apologies if I've transgressed any typical conventions for asking questions in this forum. Help with this will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How does your code example illustrate any form of hierarchy? You might want to add indentation to make your hierarchy clear.

Comment: This is [easily googleable](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+selector+nested+element). Questions here require a modicum of own research and attempts at solving an issue.

Comment: Take a look at CSS selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_Selector

Comment: I did mention that I'm not a developer. Perhaps hierarchy was the incorrect term. I did spend a lot of time on Google without success before deciding to set up an account here to ask my question. Thanks for your helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
    .faq ul {
    //your css 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could specify the ul directly as part of the article tag. I thought I had to include the headers and divs. I appreciate this very much.

Answer (score 2):

just chain them together to get to the ul

```css
article header div div ul{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
How to select a ul - within a div - within another div - within a header - within an article class


<article>
   <header>
      <div>
         <div>

            <ul>
               <li>test</li>
            </ul>

         </div>
     </div>
   </header>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this ".faq .generic-header-name-thats-found-elsewhere-in-site .generic-div-name-also-found-elsewhere .generic-child-div-name .generic-ul-class-name" .

and if it still doesn't work so I need a full code to debug.

I hope it helps

Comment: I was trying to take that approach, but I couldn't get it to work. I appreciate your reply... Elia has a working solution above.